# how to KNOW if a transaction holds exclusive lock in a row?

Tags: sql, mysql, concurrency, transactions, innodb

I am learning transactions, locks, etc and I want to know **how to know if a transaction holds exclusive lock in a row**

I tried to simulate it using the MySQL command line, but I'm not sure if it's a correct way to KNOW if a transaction holds exclusive lock in a row, could you confirm if my test is correct? I know it's working because I'm seeing it, but **maybe it's just a coincidence**.

I have tried to make this test in the sequence as is:

open transaction in connection 1:

```
begin;
UPDATE users SET rol = 'Admin' WHERE email LIKE '%example.net%';
Query OK, 182 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 182  Changed: 182  Warnings: 0
```

now, open another transaction in connection 2 (This is a row that meets the condition of connection 1):

```
begin;
UPDATE users SET rol = 'Admin' WHERE id = 11; // Blocked, it's waiting
```

now, I'm going to close transaction in Connection 1:

```
rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Immediately (automatically) connection 2:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (18.33 sec) // "Free"
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
rollback; // I close the another transaction
```

1. If my example above to KNOW if a transaction holds exclusive locks on certain rows is correct, would it work for a `DELETE` and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` since it also sets exclusive locks?

On the other hand, the documentation says as follows:

[Atomic statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)

> By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that, when not otherwise inside a transaction, **each statement is atomic**, as if it were surrounded by START TRANSACTION and COMMIT. You cannot use ROLLBACK to undo the effect; however, if an error occurs during statement execution, the statement is rolled back.

2. Does "*each statement is atomic*" refer to a **single statement** (only one)?
3. Is a single statement **still atomic** even if the condition "spans" multiple rows (e.g. the `UPDATE` of connection 1)?

Comment: I will be honest: I do not understand your question! Replicating exclusive locks mean you want to implement them in a different way. However, you seem to try to see if exclusive locks work. They do. Not really sure what your example is supposes to demonstrate regarding exlusive locks though, aa you do not keep transactions open, so any of the locks would be held for a fraction of a second.

Comment: "*However, you seem to try to see if exclusive locks work.*" - I have edited the question, that's what I want to know, to know if a transaction really has an exclusive lock in certain rows? I didn't know the right words, sorry @Shadow

Comment: You have demonstrated the locking. Locks are on indexes rather than rows. Look at `show engine innodb status` output in a third connection.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`.  Also, was rol=Admin for id=11?  Before the first Update?

Comment: Hi @Rick James, sure, I previously made sure that id = 11 meets the UPDATE condition which is in connection 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If my example above to KNOW if a transaction holds exclusive locks on certain rows is correct, would it work for a DELETE and SELECT ... FOR UPDATE since it also sets exclusive locks?

Yes, you can run similar tests for other locking statements to prove it.

> 2. Does "each statement is atomic" refer to a single statement (only one)?

Yes, autocommit mode means each single statement starts and commits one transaction.

> 3. Is a single statement still atomic even if the condition "spans" multiple rows (e.g. the UPDATE of connection 1)?

Yes. In the default transaction isolation level, the statement acquires locks on all rows it *examines.* That may be more rows than are affected by an UPDATE or returned by a SELECT, because the conditions in the query may filter the rows.

For example, in your example UPDATE:

```
UPDATE users SET rol = 'Admin' WHERE email LIKE '%example.net%';
```

The condition `LIKE` with a wildcard pattern examines all the rows in the table, even if you have defined an index on the column to search. Therefore all the rows will be locked by this UPDATE, even those rows that don't satisfy the condition.

The statement acquires locks atomically. That means it either acquires all the locks needed, or else if it fails (for instance, because some rows are already locked by another session), it must release the other locks it tried to acquire in that statement, even those that would have been successful.

Comment: The documentation says: "*In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own.*" - does that mean that any single statement (**only one**) e.g. `UPDATE table SET column = 'something' WHERE id > 1;` (without being surrounded by a transaction "explicitly") would look behind the scenes like `begin; UPDATE table SET column = 'something' WHERE id > 1; commit;`? @Bill Karwin

Comment: Yes. I think I answered that already.

Comment: Sorry, it's just that I'm new and sometimes I feel they refer to different things. It looks behind the scenes surrounded by `commit;` because "implicitly" the `rollback;` is in case the single statement fails, right? @Bill Karwin

Comment: If it fails, the statement has no effect. That's implies by the statement being atomic. It updates no rows, and any locks it acquired are released. At that point, it doesn't matter if it commits or rolls back the transaction, since there is no effect either way.

Comment: Excellent, now it is a bit clearer. Here in MySQL, are **any kind of lock** *released* once the transaction is *finished*? @Bill Karwin

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html: _"Both COMMIT and ROLLBACK release all InnoDB locks that were set during the current transaction."_

Comment: Great!!! Thanks for citing the documentation, it's always best to **back up information** with official citations. I still don't read all the documentation, that's why I didn't realize that. Sorry, I can't give +1 to your answer due to my reputation, but when I have some reputation I'll stop by and leave my +1.